# Where will the default _logger file be stored?

Tags: asp.net-core

Created a sample webAPI(5.0) in asp.net core. It comes with WeatherForecastController.cs

Now this is the code :

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("entered");
        var rng = new Random();
        _logger.LogInformation("exited");
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
       
    }
```

I entered the _logger.LogInformation("entered");

Now where will I find this information ? will there be any file located? I am in an understanding that a file will be created and all this logging info will be stored.

this is my startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        services.AddControllers()
          .AddFluentValidation(s =>
          {
              s.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
             
          });


        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebApi", Version = "v1" });
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly.FullName)));

        #region Repositories
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        services.AddTransient<IDeveloperRepository, DeveloperRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        #endregion

      

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebApi v1"));
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default is it logging to the output console.

[image: Output Console]

You can find more information about ASP.NET Core logging [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)